# Executing code after an update

Tags: ios, swift

I have a live app that has cached data. When I send out an update on test flight or to the app store I want the app to clear the cached data.

Is there an way to execute a line of code like `clearCacheResults()` on a update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the version no in defaults

```
let version: AnyObject? = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(version, forKey: "appversion")
```

More info on the bundle keys available here in the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-102364-TPXREF106)

> First time this will be nil. however on next launch you can retrieve
>   the previous stored version from defaults

```
let oldVersion: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("appversion")

and compare
if (oldVersion != version) {
   // clear cache
}
```